# Javascript function logic

Tags: javascript, function

I have 3 js functions passing into each other for a blackjack game,

**Hit()** - Which gets a new card

**checkCard(**) - which checks the card isnt in the users hand already

**userTotal ()** - totals the value of the card and displays it in the DOM

The same card can appear more than once. the major flaw is with checking the card against others in an array of userCards

My logic is wrong. Could someone help me?

```
function hit() {
    var cards = 2;
    userIndex++;
    var rankSelect = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    var suitSelect = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var card = (rank[rankSelect] + suit[suitSelect]);
    checkCard(card);
}


function checkCard(card) {
//if card = card in used array, select new card
for (i=0;i<=userCards.length;i++){
        if (card = userCards[i] ) {
            //selectCards(card)
                var newRank = Math.floor(Math.random()*13);
                var newSuit = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
                var newCard = (rank[newRank] + suit[newSuit]);
                document.getElementById('userCards').innerHTML += "<td id=" + "UserCard" + "><img src="+"includes/images/cards/"+ newCard + ".png >"
                userCards[userCards.length] = newCard;
                userTotal();
        } else {
                userCards[userIndex] = card;
                document.getElementById('userCards').innerHTML += "<td id=" + "UserCard" + "><img src="+"includes/images/cards/"+ card + ".png >"
                userTotal();
            }
        }
}

function userTotal(userTotal){
    var userTotal = 0;
    for (i=0;i<userCards.length;i++){
        var value = userCards[i];
            if(userCards[i].charAt(0) == "a"){
                value = parseInt((prompt("ACE, 1 or 11?")));
                userTotal = userTotal + value;
                document.getElementById("userTotal").innerHTML = userTotal;
            } else if (userCards[i].charAt(0) == "k" || userCards[i].charAt(0) == "q" || userCards[i].charAt(0) == "j"){
                value = 10;
                userTotal = userTotal + value;
                document.getElementById("userTotal").innerHTML = userTotal;
            }else if (userCards[i].charAt(0) == "1" || userCards[i].charAt(1) == "0"){
                value = 10;
                userTotal = userTotal + value;
                document.getElementById("userTotal").innerHTML = userTotal;
            } else {
                value = parseInt(userCards[i].charAt(0));
                userTotal = userTotal + value;
                document.getElementById("userTotal").innerHTML = userTotal;
            }
        if (userTotal > 21){
            document.getElementById("userTotal").innerHTML = "Bust";
            //document.getElementById("hit").disabled = true;
        }
            }
    }
```

Comment: In precisely what way is your logic wrong? What's not working? *How*, and in what way, is it 'not working'?

Comment: @DavidThomas the same card can appear more than once. the major flaw is with checking the card against others in an array of userCards

Comment: You can open a console log by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+i in chrome, or installing and activating FireBug in FireFox, it will probably give you an error that we could work with.

Comment: @NemanjaT there is no errors in syntax :(

Comment: Thank you. Please [edit] that information into your question where people are more likely to see, and read, it when working out whether they want to try and answer your question or not. :)

Comment: @DavidThomas Here is an example of the code in use http://ipt.hillcrest.qld.edu.au/erourke15/SPA/

Comment: Should your `var rankSelect = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);` not be to 12 instead as it will return 0 in some cases? Not the issue but it seems you include a card that don't exist. Same goes for `suitSelect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are inside 'checkCard' and if you get a card already in hand then you are again fetching a random card but this time you are not checking whether its already in hand or not.

You need to keep checking card until you won't get a fresh one.

replace this line :

var newCard = (rank[newRank] + suit[newSuit]);

with

card = (rank[newRank] + suit[newSuit]);
 checkCard(card);

Try below :

```
    function hit() {
        var cards = 2;
        userIndex++;
        var rankSelect = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
        var suitSelect = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        var card = (rank[rankSelect] + suit[suitSelect]);
        checkCard(card);
    }


    function checkCard(card) {
        //if card = card in used array, select new card
        for (i = 0; i <= userCards.length; i++) {
            if (card = userCards[i]) {
                //selectCards(card)
                var newRank = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
                var newSuit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
                card = (rank[newRank] + suit[newSuit]);
                chekCard(card);
                document.getElementById('userCards').innerHTML += "<td id=" + "UserCard" + "><img src=" + "includes/images/cards/" + card + ".png >"
                userCards[userCards.length] = card;
                userTotal();
            } else {
                userCards[userIndex] = card;
                document.getElementById('userCards').innerHTML += "<td id=" + "UserCard" + "><img src=" + "includes/images/cards/" + card + ".png >"
                userTotal();
            }
        }
    }

    function userTotal(userTotal) {
        var userTotal = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < userCards.length; i++) {
            var value = userCards[i];
            if (userCards[i].charAt(0) == "a") {
                value = parseInt((prompt("ACE, 1 or 11?")));
                userTotal = userTotal + value;
                document.getElementById("userTotal").innerHTML = userTotal;
            } else if (userCards[i].charAt(0) == "k" || userCards[i].charAt(0) == "q" || userCards[i].charAt(0) == "j") {
                value = 10;
                userTotal = userTotal + value;
                document.getElementById("userTotal").innerHTML = userTotal;
            } else if (userCards[i].charAt(0) == "1" || userCards[i].charAt(1) == "0") {
                value = 10;
                userTotal = userTotal + value;
                document.getElementById("userTotal").innerHTML = userTotal;
            } else {
                value = parseInt(userCards[i].charAt(0));
                userTotal = userTotal + value;
                document.getElementById("userTotal").innerHTML = userTotal;
            }
            if (userTotal > 21) {
                document.getElementById("userTotal").innerHTML = "Bust";
                //document.getElementById("hit").disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Like this? checkCard(newCard);

Comment: edited my answer with code try that.

replace this line :

var newCard = (rank[newRank] + suit[newSuit]);

with

card = (rank[newRank] + suit[newSuit]); checkCard(card);

Comment: basically, you need not to create a new card variable. Just use your old variable 'card' and assign new values to it and perform and checCard on that.

Comment: have you removed newCard completely from your code, as suggested?

Comment: Yes, chrome console gives this error "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: can you provide 'prompt' function. or its better if you can create a fiddle with your code.